# Validation dependency between inputs in angular2 form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to find the best way to have validations that link two components.

Say I have two checkboxes.
I want the second input to be required only when the first one is checked.

I'm just starting out with validations and am not sure exactly how I could do this.

I guess I could just change the validation rules in my component.ts file when using model driven forms.

Would that be the good way of dealing with this? Or are there helpers to handle such cases?

Comment: You can define custom validation rules (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation) for both model fields, bound to the two checkboxes. Thus you can determine whether the model is valid or not based on its current state. Another option would be to define a custom component that contains both checkboxes, implementing ControlValueAccessor interface (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html), but this will be overkill IMHO. It really depends on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable named checbox1checked, and assign an initial value of false to it.

let checbox1checked: boolean = false;

if a user checked checkbox1, assign  checbox1checked the value of true.

while validating checkbox2 check to see if checbox1checked is true, if yes then show your error message for checkbox2, if not ignore your checkbox2 error message.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this:

```
<input type="checkbox2" [attr.required]="checked1">
<input type="checkbox1" [(ngModel)]="checked1">
```